# Second form not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have created two different forms, one for the user to select values and the other for displaying all the total costs.

I did declare an instance of the other class and passed it the two variables that held charges. Within the second class I had a constructor accept the arguments and then assign them to variables within the second form.

When trying to display the results on the second for by using the ".ShowDialog();" method, the form appears blank, nothing on it.

First form:

```
namespace DormAndMeal
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        int ALLENPRICE = 1500;
        int PIKEPRICE = 1600;
        int FARTHINGPRICE = 1800;
        int UNIVERSITYPRICE = 2500;

        int MEAL7 = 600;
        int MEAL14 = 1200;
        int UNLIMITEDMEAL = 1700;



        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // close
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int roomCharge = 0;
            int foodCharge = 0;

            // Checking for the room plan chosen, assigning price to roomCharge
            if (radAllen.Checked)
            {
                roomCharge = ALLENPRICE;
            }
            else if (radPike.Checked)
            {
                roomCharge = PIKEPRICE;
            }
            else if (radFarthing.Checked)
            {
                roomCharge = FARTHINGPRICE;
            }
            else if (radUniversity.Checked)
            {
                roomCharge = UNIVERSITYPRICE;
            }


            // Checking for which meal plan was selected, assign price to foodCharge
            if (radMeal1.Checked)
            {
                foodCharge = MEAL7;
            }
            else if (radMeal2.Checked)
            {
                foodCharge = MEAL14;
            }
            else if (radMeal3.Checked)
            {
                foodCharge = UNLIMITEDMEAL;
            }

            // Instance of Charges form
            Charges myCharges = new Charges(foodCharge, roomCharge);

            // Display the form
            myCharges.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the form finds which radio buttons were selected and assigns prices accordingly, then it creates an instance of the second form and shows it.

form 2:

```
namespace DormAndMeal
{
    public partial class Charges : Form
    {
        int foodTotal;
        int roomTotal;

        public Charges()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Charges(int food, int room)
        {
            this.roomTotal = room;
            this.foodTotal = food;
        }

        private void Charges_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblFood.Text = foodTotal.ToString("c");
            lblRoom.Text = roomTotal.ToString("c");

            lblTotal.Text = (foodTotal + roomTotal).ToString("c");
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // close
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This form has a constructor to accept the arguments and assign them, then go through and display them to the appropriate variables located on the form.

For some reason the second form shows up blank.

Comment: So the second form is supposed to have a button and 3 labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling the `InitializeComponents` method, which will create all of the controls from the designer file:

```
public Charges(int food, int room)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.roomTotal = room;
  this.foodTotal = food;
}
```

or as pointed out in comments, you can call your other constructor:

```
public Charges()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public Charges(int food, int room)
  : this()
{
  this.roomTotal = room;
  this.foodTotal = food;
}
```

Comment: For clarification/extra explanation: Just because you make another constructor does not mean that it will call previous ones. All the logic in one must be copied over to the other. Better yet, have both constructors call a common function to do the "setup", then do your unique logic after.

Comment: I would call the base constructor (using `: this()`) rather than calling `InitializeComponent` in each constructor.

Comment: public Charges(int food, int room) : this() is good syntax to get the default constructor to run.